# editing file at multiple places using tcl/tk patterns

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a file in which I have to search for "if statement" and corresponding "end if statement" . Currently I am doing it using lsearch( separately for "if" and "end if" and then using lappend to combine the two). Problem arises when there is cascaded if statement, which makes it difficult to identify the related "if" and "end if" pairs.  If there is no assignment between the two statements then I use lreplace to delete the lines between the if and end if pair. This has to run in loop because there are multiple such pairs. Every time lreplace is used, lsearch is used again to calculate the new indexes. I am finding that this is very inefficient implementation. Can anyone suggest some pointers to improve the same.

Comment: Could you perhaps put a sample of the file and the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple thing to do. The issue is that you're really needing a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) rather than a simple [finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Simple searching won't cut it.

What you can do though is this: go through and replace each `if` and `end if` keyword with characters otherwise unused (`\u0080` and `\u0081` are good candidates; the C1 controls are really obscure). Then you can use a simple match in a loop to pick off each inner pair while requiring there to be no unmatched `\u0080`/`\u0081` inside. With each match, you get swap the characters back to the tokens and do the other processing you want at the same time. Once there are no more matches, you're done.

```
set txt [string map {"end if" "\u0081" "if" "\u0080"} $txt]
while {[regexp -indices {\u0080[^\u0080\u0081]*\u0081} $txt span]} {
    set bit [string map {"\u0081" "end if" "\u0080" "if"} [string range $txt {*}$span]]
    puts "matched $bit"
    # ...
    set txt [string replace $txt $bit {*}$span]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How to use eval(tcl version 8.4) command instead of argument expansion in the following :                    set bit [string map {"\u0081" "end if" "\u0080" "if"} [string range $txt {*}$span]]